# SQL (oracle) Update some records in table A using values in table B

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to tables :

```
Table1
--------------------------------
ID         VAL1       DATE1
--------------------------------
1          1          20/03/2015
2          null       null
3          1          10/01/2015
4          0          12/02/2015
5          null       null

Table2
--------------------------------
ID         VAL2       DATE1
--------------------------------
1          N          02/06/2015
2          null       null
3          O          05/04/2015
4          O          01/07/2015
5          O          03/02/2015
```

I want to update :

- column VAL1 of Table1 with '0', if VAL2 of Table2 is equal to 'O'
- column DATE1 of Table1 with DATE2 of Table2

(This two tables are not so simple, it's just for illustration, they can be joined with the ID column).

So the expected result is :

```
Table1
--------------------------------
ID         VAL1       DATE1
--------------------------------
1          1          20/03/2015
2          null       null
3          0          05/04/2015
4          0          01/07/2015
5          0          03/02/2015
```

Here my code :

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
SET t1.VAL1 = '0',
SET t1.DATE1 = (SELECT t2.DATE2 from Table2 t2
                INNER JOIN Table1 t1
                ON trim(t2.ID)=trim(t1.ID))
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
              FROM Table2 t2
              WHERE trim(t2.ID) = trim(t1.ID)
              AND t2.Table2 = 'O');
```

The part that make my code not working is : (esle working)

```
SET t1.DATE1 = (SELECT t2.DATE2 from Table2 t2
                    INNER JOIN Table1 t1
                    ON trim(t2.ID)=trim(t1.ID))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a correlated subquery, not a `join` in the subquery.  So, assuming the rest of the logic is correct:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
    SET t1.VAL1 = '0',
        t1.DATE1 = (SELECT t2.DATE2 
                    FROM Table2 t2
                    WHERE trim(t2.ID) = trim(t1.ID))
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Table2 t2
                  WHERE trim(t2.ID) = trim(t1.ID) AND
                        t2.Table2 = 'O'
                 );
```

Comment: I get an error : _ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row_
Looks like it's because in Table2 there are several lines with same IDs. So how can I do to take the most earlier date for each ID in this case? Maybe using an over( partition by ..) ?

Comment: Ok I resolved it with an order by : `SET t1.VAL1 = '0',
t1.DATE1 = (SELECT * from (select t2.DATE2  
                    FROM Table2 t2, Table1 t1
                    WHERE trim(t2.ID) = trim(t1.ID)
                    ORDER BY T2.DATE2 ASC
            )`
Thank you